# ORACLE JSON_TABLE I need to get 2 columns from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, unnest

I have this SQL code

```
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE (('
[
    "tipodenunciaid": [1,2],
    "municipioid": [1,2]
]
'), '$[*]' COLUMNS (tipodenunciaid integer PATH '$.tipodenunciaid[*]', municipioid integer PATH '$.municipioid[*]'));
```

And I want to get the next result:

[image: Like This]

What's wrong with my query?

Thank you so much.

Comment: How does the input and output relate? What happened with values `4`and `5` of `municipioid`?

Comment: the output is just an example of how I need the structure.

Comment: You would need to show us the actual output you want for this specific data. Otherwise it is rather unclear what exactly you are after.

Comment: I just need those 2 arrays to turn into 2 columns..

Comment: You can't do that with JSON functions alone - for the trivial reason that JSON structure assigns no meaning to array values of separate attributes. The biggest issue is your input data, not your query. If those values were supposed to be related as you are showing in your output, the JSON should be an array of objects, each with the two attributes you have at the top level in *your* JSON. The way you have your data now, you will need to extract the array values to columns in two separate subqueries, and then join by ordinality.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `json_table()` like that. If you want both arrays unnested in different columns, and lined up according to the position of each element in each array, then one option would be to separately expand each array to rows, using `ordinality` to keep track of the position of each element, then join the two resultsets. A `full join` comes handy to accommodate for an unequal number of elements in each array:

```
with 
    data as (
        select '{ "tipodenunciaid": [1,2,3,4], "municipioid": [1,2,3,4,5] }' as js from dual
    ),
    t as (
        select t.*
        from data d
        cross apply json_table(
            d.js,
            '$.tipodenunciaid[*]' columns (rn for ordinality, tipodenunciaid integer path '$')
        ) t
    ),
    m as (
        select m.*
        from data d
        cross apply json_table(
            d.js,
            '$.municipioid[*]' columns (rn for ordinality, municipioid integer path '$')
        ) m
    )
select t.tipodenunciaid, m.municipioid
from t
full join m on m.rn = t.rn
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b4ca573406884a10d8683d7cade0c44)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `OUTER APPLY`s with `FOR ORDINALITY` to generate the ordinates of the array to connect the table to itself:

```sql
SELECT j.id,
       CASE
       WHEN t.id = m.id OR t.id > m.max_id OR m.id IS NULL
       THEN tipodenunciaid
       END AS tipodenunciaid,
       CASE
       WHEN t.id = m.id OR m.id > t.max_id OR t.id IS NULL
       THEN municipioid
       END AS municipioid
FROM   table_name j
       OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT id,
                tipodenunciaid,
                MAX(id) OVER () AS  max_id
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  j.json,
                  '$.tipodenunciaid[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    id FOR ORDINALITY,
                    tipodenunciaid integer PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) t
       OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT id,
                municipioid,
                MAX(id) OVER () AS  max_id
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  j.json,
                  '$.municipioid[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    id FOR ORDINALITY,
                    municipioid integer PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) m
WHERE  t.id = m.id
OR     t.id IS NULL
OR     ( m.id > t.max_id AND t.id = t.max_id )
OR     m.id IS NULL
OR     ( t.id > m.max_id AND m.id = m.max_id );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, json ) AS
SELECT 1, '{"tipodenunciaid":[1,2],"municipioid":[1,2]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '{"tipodenunciaid":[],"municipioid":[3,4]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '{"tipodenunciaid":[5],"municipioid":[]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '{"tipodenunciaid":[6,7],"municipioid":[6]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '{"tipodenunciaid":[8],"municipioid":[8,9]}' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | TIPODENUNCIAID | MUNICIPIOID
> -: | -------------: | ----------:
>  1 |              1 |           1
>  1 |              2 |           2
>  2 |           null |           3
>  2 |           null |           4
>  3 |              5 |        null
>  4 |              6 |           6
>  4 |              7 |        null
>  5 |              8 |           8
>  5 |           null |           9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f19d68e16533b4e2fd73c864cf74f6b)*